# arrayList to json obj using spring mvc

Tags: java, json, spring, arraylist

I need to find an optimised way to pass an `arraylist` as `json` a obj to the controller using spring `mvc`.

Currently I am doing it this way:

```
public @ResponseBody List<String> abcd() throws Exception {
    return listString;
}
```

but it is returning a normal list type object. I need a proper `json` obj which can be accessed by angular js.

Comment: There are a ton of Java libraries for conversion from and to JSON. Please research. Also, do not use raw types (`List` instead of `List<Something>`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ResponseBody` should return a JSON object but here is what you can try:

```
public @ResponseBody ArrayList<YourObject>
    myFunction(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/json");     
    return yourArrayList;`
}
```

You can also try returning a Map instead. Keep your return type as `Map <String, Object>` and put your `ArrayList` in the map. This will also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your list inside an object like

```
class JSONResponse{
 List<String> names;
 //other nodes of JSON
}
```

Return the object as response You can also replace String with the objects you desire. Please post the code if you need clear help.